# Giant baby scene cut out of Benjamin Button?

Tags: alternate-version, the-curious-case-of-benjamin-button

I think I remember seeing a quick shot of the cronologically older and therefore younger Benjamin Button in a trailer for the movie. I can't find this anywhere now. It seems logical that a scene like this might have been shot. Benjamin starts small and wrinkled and grows bigger and younger. When he dies he should be giant (adult-size) baby, fetus, or cell. Was there ever a scene showing him in this state? Did I imagine seeing it?

Comment: Button becomes a "child" near the end of the movie, but not a giant one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was this scene with a baby where the girlfriend of Benjamin Button was sitting on a chair and holding the baby. She looked very sad. The baby's eyes were closed.

Comment: We usually look for long and  motivated answers...

Comment: I don't know why he shrank to a baby. He started a wrinkly baby and grew, he should end a smooth man. Maybe I imagined him as a large baby.

Comment: @mattiav27 who are we ?